# Linux environment variable using non-fullpath

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables

I'm setting the environment variable LD_PRELOAD to a shared library file I created, in order to let LD_PRELOAD to point to my created shared library file, I need to give the full path like this:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=full/path/to/file.so
```

but if I point the LD_PRELOAD to a shared library under `/usr/lib/`, I don't need to give the full path, I don't have root privilege so I cannot put my shared library file to `/usr/lib/`, in such case, how can I set the environment variable LD_PRELOAD using non-fullpath like this:

```
 export LD_PRELOAD=file.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best you put all the `.so` files in a directory you have access and append that path of `.so` files with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Something like below:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:path_to_your_lib
```

Remember whenever you close the shell, you have to do it again. You can either put in a script or bash profile.